# Ripristinate Krita icon on tool bar

Tags: updates, icons, krita

After one routine update, the icon for Krita (installed with snap on Ubuntu 22.04) has disappeared. T tried with `sudo apt-get install oxygen-icon-theme` but nothing.

How can I repristinate it?

Thank you